# Floating points in C++ (float and double)

Tags: c++, loops, floating-point, double, rounding-error

I know that we shouldn't use floating points in the loops. But could someone explain it to me what happens when we have a loop and we add a small number to a large number until we reach a certain value that allows the loop to terminate?
I guess it might cause potential errors. But apart from that?

What would it look like with a single-precision (float) and double-precision (double) floating-point numbers? I guess more rounding errors would appear in the double type. Could someone give me an example (the best in C ++) because I have no idea how to start with it...

I would be very grateful if you could provide me with a hint. Thanks!

Comment: "I know that we shouldn't use floating points in the loops. " . That is a misunderstanding. For instance, in Newton's root finding algorithm you loop until an error is small enough, and that error will be a floating-point number.

Answer (score 2):

In  a C++ implementation using IEEE-754 arithmetic and the “single” (binary32) format for `float`, this code prints “count = 3”:

```
int count = 0;
for (float f = 0; f < .3f; f += .1f)
    ++count;
std::cout << "count = " << count << ".\n";
```

but this code prints “count = 4”:

```
int count = 0;
for (float f = 0; f < .33f; f += .11f)
    ++count;
std::cout << "count = " << count << ".\n";
```

In the first example, the source text `.1f` is converted to 0.100000001490116119384765625, which is the value representable in `float` that is closed to .1. The source text `.3f` is converted to 0.300000011920928955078125, the `float` value closest to .3. Adding this converted value for `.1f` to `f` produces 0.100000001490116119384765625, then 0.20000000298023223876953125, and then 0.300000011920928955078125, at which point `f < .3f` is false, and the loop stops.

In the second example, `.11f` is converted to 0.10999999940395355224609375, and `.33f` is converted to 0.3300000131130218505859375. In this case, adding the converted value of `.11f` to `f` produces 0.10999999940395355224609375, then 0.2199999988079071044921875, and then 0.329999983310699462890625. Note that, due to rounding, this result of adding `.11f` three times is 0.329999983310699462890625, which is less than `.33f` (0.3300000131130218505859375), so `f < .33f` is true, and the loop continues for another iteration.

This is similar to adding ⅓ in a two-digit decimal format with a loop bound of three-thirds (which is 1). If we had `for (f = 0; f < 1; f += ⅓)`, the `⅓` in the source text would have to be converted to .33 (two-digit decimal). Then `f` would be stepped through .33, .66, and .99. The loop would not stop until it reached 1.32. The same rounding issues occur in binary floating-point arithmetic.

When the amount added in the loop is a small number relative to the large number, these rounding issues are greater. First, there will be more additions, so there will be more rounding errors, and they may accumulate. Second, since larger numbers require a larger exponent to scale them in the floating-point format, they have less absolute precision than smaller numbers. This means the roundings have to be come larger relative to the small number that is being added. So the rounding errors are larger in magnitude.

Then, even if the loop eventually terminates, the values of `f` in each iteration may be far from the desired values, due to the accumulated errors. If `f` is used for calculations inside the loop, the calculations might not be using the desired values and may produce incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

With increasing values the difference between 2 floating point values increases too. There is a point where `i+1` results in the same value.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    float i = 0;
    while (i != i + 1) i++;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`while (i != i + 1)` should be an endless loop, but for floating point variables, it is not.
The code above prints `1.67772e+07` on https://godbolt.org/z/7xf8n8

So, `for (float f = 0; f < 2e7; f++)` is an endless loop.

You can try it with `double` yourself, the value is bigger.